# How would I test my login function has been called? Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spy

I am struggling with how to test if a function has been called between a component and a service.

If there is something I'm missing, please educate me!

Comment: I'd recommend reading [the testing guidance](https://angular.io/guide/testing); you shouldn't be unit testing the component with a real service with the real HTTP client.

Comment: Hmm ok then. I will have a read and see what I can come up with. 
Any quick hints in the mean time?

Comment: Instead of using `HttpClientModule`, maybe you can use `HttpClientTestingModule`.

Comment: @SourangshuSengupta that would be if you were testing the *service*, the component shouldn't know anything about that.

Comment: The short answer is: your "form" isn't valid, so the service isn't called. But that's probably just as well: why are you explicitly calling through to the service, even though that's not what you're testing? The point of extracting that logic to a service is that the component doesn't know about it, you shouldn't be calling or even necessarily using the real service, and unit tests should generally never use real HTTP.

Comment: In your `onSubmit()` method, you are checking if the form is valid, and only then calling the service method. Is it possible that `validFormGoodCreds` that you are using in your test is *not* `valid`?? I don't see a valid property on it.

Answer (score 0):

in your specs, you name the auth service `authServ`:

`(authServ: AuthService) => {`

but you're spying on `auth`:

`spy = spyOn(auth, 'login').and.callThrough();`

Can you try renaming the auth service `authServ` => `auth`?

If this doesn't help, please post the error message(s), otherwise it's hard to debug.

Comment: Apologies for that, I'd been changing code as I copied it over.
Doing as such gets the error: Expected spy login to have been called.

Comment: this means, it hasn't been called. alternatively, for debugging you can set a console.log or a breakpoint, if you use a IDE that allows you to debug angular (e.g. visual studio code)